# In version 9, is there a way to unpublish items directly from the recycle bin

Tags: publishing

Is there a way to unpublish items directly from the recycle bin rather than having to restore them and then unpublish them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can query items in the recycle bin and then delete the corresponding items from the publishing target.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible to execute any action like that from recycle bin directly.

What you could think of is removing items from the `web` database manually, but that can cause issues like indexes being out of sync.

Proper way would be to restore the item and unpublish it.

Long time ago I wrote a command for Sitecore backend which allows to unpublish and delete item with one click. Maybe something like that would help for the future?

https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-unpublish-and-delete-item